# How to make my button tag to trigger my input tag secretly, without seeing my input tag?

Tags: reactjs

**Question:**

I am new to React. For some reason, I would like to hide my input tag. On the other hand, I want a button tag to perform what my existing input do, which is to load file and set the content of files into variables.

**Problem explanation:**

My input tag could load files and set the file content into variable. However, the style of input tag is not my liking and i prefer the style of my button components.
So, as far as I know, only input tag could do the loading file feature.

But since I have wrote the function I need in the input tag, which is to load file and load the content into a variable. I want to see if I can make the button pretended as input. So I dont have to rewrite code again
So, is it possible to let my button to somehow pretend the input tag?

**Below is my present code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState("");
  const handleChange = e => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      console.log("e.target.result", e.target.result);
      setFiles(e.target.result);
    };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Upload Json file - Example</h1>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      {"uploaded file content -- " + files}
      <br />
     // I expect when I click on "Import file", it could also load file like the input tag and perform what my existing input tag do
      <button >Import file</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: did try styling that input tag like your button component ? or maybe placing the input inside button.

Comment: Actally its not like the standard button, the button component is from a libray I like . I tried to put it into the button, but it become weird. You try to simply put that into it and you will know what I mean, using my code

Comment: What do you want exactly? Pretend the visual of `<button>` as `<input>` or the _Import file_ button could trigger load file actions as `<input>`?

Comment: Yes, I want the Import file button could trigger load file actions as <input>. But since I have wrote the function I need in the input tag, which is to load file and load the content into variable. I want to see if I can make the <button> pretended as <input>. So I  dont have to rewrite code again

Comment: You could make `onClick` on the button manually call `.click` on a reference to the input, maybe? Though I'm sure there's an easier way, and this way feels very hacky. Also, keep accessibility in mind when doing this, as you'll likely be damaging default accessibility by not using `input`.

Comment: Or, is it possible to make button be able to load file like input tag? then I just copy the handling code into button tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of ways.

One is to give the `input` element an `id` and then insert a `label` inside the button with the `for` attribute set to the same id.

```
<input id="upload" type="file" onChange={handleChange}/>
```

and

```
<button><label htmlFor="upload">Import file</label></button>
```

(***note**: only the clicking on the text will trigger the input, so you might need some css here to make the label fill the button completely*)

---

Another would be to use a `ref` on the `input` and use it to trigger a click on it from your button.

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.click();
};

<input ref={inputRef} type="file" onChange={handleChange}/>

<button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Import file</button>
```

Both attempts shown at: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sound-l0hhzm

Comment: For first approach, I got a error for using lable attribute  -Warning: Invalid DOM property `%s`. Did you mean `%s`?%s for htmlForat label

Comment: right, use `htmlFor`. I used the standard html attribute instead of the react one.

Comment: In attempt two, may I know that can I hide the input tag too, while it does exist in my code? just want to not show it

Comment: I mean it would not occupy any space at all as well

Comment: I figured it out at the end!

Comment: Would you mind upvoting my question, so other may see our discussion too? I upvoted your answer as well

Comment: @AeLeung you can hide it with css `display:none`

Comment: I got a error in approach2, it said TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' for my input Ref

Comment: @AeLeung, oh you are using typescript. Try `const inputRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);` instead and the use it as `if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.click();`

Comment: Then I got this : TS2322: Type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'. Type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'. Types of property 'current' are incompatible.

Comment: May I ask, when I write  ref={inputRef} , does it mean I am assigning a ref into a input tag? That means I should use HTMLInputElement, right?

Comment: The way I look at useRef<HTMLInputElement> means the inputRef onlu accept HTMLInputElement, but it also takes null?

Comment: @AeLeung Right, use `HTMLInputElement`.  The `ref={inputRef}` is a react feature which allows the element reference to be stored to a variable so you can access it directly without needing to query it from the DOM.